# Why does the graphic indicator not show for milestone task?

Tags: ms-project

Why for milestone task, the graphic indicator did not show?

The formula to consider is the following:

```
IIf(CDbl([Baseline Finish]>60000)," Not Baseline",IIf(([Baseline Duration]=0 Or [Duration]=0),Switch([% Complete]=100," Completed",[Status Date]<[Start]," Not Start Yet",[Status Date]>[Start],"Late"),Switch([Status Date]<[Start]," Not Start Yet",[% Complete]=100,"Completed",(ProjDateDiff([Start],[Status Date])/480)/Val(ProjDurConv(Duration,pjDays))*100<=[% Complete],"Ahead Schedule",(ProjDateDiff([Start],[Status Date])/480)/Val(ProjDurConv(Duration,pjDays))*100>[% Complete],"Late")))
```

Comment: More information is needed. To start: 1) What field contains this formula? 2) What did you expect to see in that field? 3) What did you actually see instead?

Comment: The field contain this formula is text field. What I expect to see is it show graphic indicator for the case " Not Start Yet", "Completed", " Ahead Schedule" or " Late". What my actual saw is for the normal task which already started it work well, but other normal task which have not start yet and milestone task it does not work

Answer (score 1):

With a slight modification to the formula it works without error for the milestones. Be sure to check the graphical indicators set up to be sure the text matches--your formula has a space before two of the values: " Completed", " Not Start Yet".

Here's the updated formula which changes a < to <= in the first Switch statement ([Status Date]<=[Start])

```
IIf(CDbl([Baseline Finish]>60000)," Not Baseline",IIf(([Baseline Duration]=0 Or [Duration]=0),
Switch([% Complete]=100," Completed",[Status Date]<=[Start]," Not Start Yet",[Status Date]>[Start],"Late"),
Switch([Status Date]<[Start]," Not Start Yet",[% Complete]=100,"Completed",(ProjDateDiff([Start],[Status Date])/480)/Val(ProjDurConv(Duration,pjDays))*100<=[% Complete],"Ahead Schedule",(ProjDateDiff([Start],[Status Date])/480)/Val(ProjDurConv(Duration,pjDays))*100>[% Complete],"Late")))
```